# How do I replace the player with a rigid body object? BGE

Tags: animation, game-engine, workflow, rigid-body-simulation

I have a character who's like a snail with legs in a hard metal ball. He's animated to run, stand still, and curl up inside the ball. For my game-play, I would like the ball to roll off like a completely normal rigid-body object. Unfortunately, it is parented to the armature. once the snail is curled, it remains where it is, no physics.

How can I have my snail curl up into his ball and roll away? I feel like this could be done by ending the object and adding a rigid body ball, but then how do I get the snail back when it's time to uncurl? It present yet another problem if you parent the snails armature to the rigid body ball: where does the ball go when the snail unfolds? how can I guarantee that proper rotation will be kept on the snails body?

I don't need a "solution", but I do need more ideas on what to try in order for this to work. I've tried literally all day, spent every idea I’ve had, and now i just need more things to test before I give up.

[image]

Okay, heres my most recent test.
[image]

Space-bar switches mode. its pretty easy to see the problem.

Answer (score 1):

when you press space. use python to add a invisible ball.

parent the snails physics object to the ball no collision.

the snail,should be

Cube (physics,bound)

---

armature parented to cube

---

skin parented to armature

---

and the ball should be a rigid body,

invisible, sphere physics, bound

your going to want to use python and a timer to do it

let me know if you need more help.

Comment: yeah... um, how can i parent the player cube as no-collision, and then recover it?

Comment: when parented ghost to the rigid body, you just unparent and delete rigid body to 'recover' the original physics , you will also need to do object.alignAxisToVect(Vector([0,0,1]),2,1)